# Poster Image for video in WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I manage to show and play a video using HTML in WebView by loading the following HTML:

```
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"+
            "<html><head><title></title><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><script type=\"text/javascript\"></script></head>\n" +
            "<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\"><div id=\"video\"><video id=\"vid\" height=\"180\" width=\"320\" poster controls><source src=\"http://d21dkag2w1645r.cloudfront.net/article_videos/fcce6da21f4a88ffff297a7af9769b4e50f070f8.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></div></body></html>";
```

However, I cant get the video's poster image to load. I would expect this to be auto-loaded by the webview by getting the first frame of the video, but this does not seem to happen and my webview jsut shows a blank background with the controls. How can I get the webview to auto-load the poster image/first frame of the video and show it as a placeholder?

Comment: I pasted your code into my web app. I can see the poster image of the video without any problem though.

Comment: I see the same problem in my app in android...